# I figured out the code for testing equal a's and b's in a list but can't understand the underlying recursion

Tags: list, prolog, difference-lists

```
s(A,A).
s(A,D):- l(A,B),s(B,C),r(C,D).

l([a|A],A).

r([b|A],A).
```

The above code in prolog checks if the given input of a list has equal a's and b's or not.

Such as

```
s([a,a,b,b],[]).
True.
```

This involves recursion and difference lists. Can anyone explains how the underlying recursion checks equal a's with b's step by step.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

List differences are not easy to understand if you reason about them at a low level.

Therefore, I first recommend a more high-level view:

Over all, your predicate `s/2` describes a *list*. I say "describes", because it not only "checks", but also *generates* and *completes* such lists if we want!

We can read each goal of `s/2` as "and *then* some element(s) of the list".

So, forget about the arguments for a moment and consider the abstract *structure* of the predicate. I use `(-->)/2` now instead of `(:-)/2` to make clear that I am talking about a small variation of the predicate, where I simply ignore the arguments:

```
s --> [].
s --> l, s, r.
```

We can do the same with `l/2` and `r/2`:

```
l --> [a].
r --> [b].
```

This is what the predicates describe in an abstract, *high-level* view of the lists. In this notation, I need not wrestle with list differences and arguments. Instead, I can focus directly on the *essence* of the program.

It is obvious that you can easily translate such high-level code to the code that you posted. In fact, Prolog performs this translation for you if you consult this code: It is called **DCG notation**. See [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg) for more information.

So, it now is clear: `s//0` describes a list that is either *empty*, or:

- a list described by `l//0`
- *and then* a list described by `s//0`
- *and then* a list described by `r//0`.

Since `l//0` describes a list with a single element `a`, and `r//0` describes a list with a single element `b`, it is clear that in the lists that `s//0` describes, there is always the same number of `a`s and `b`s.

We use `phrase/2` to invoke a DCG. For example:

```
?- phrase(s, Ls).
Ls = [] ;
Ls = [a, b] ;
Ls = [a, a, b, b] ;
Ls = [a, a, a, b, b, b] .
```

If you start to reason about recursion explicitly, you will not make much progress, because it quickly gets too hard to trace the exact steps that are performed by the Prolog engine, and to take all possibilities into account. I recommend you focus on the meaning of your predicates, and try to understand what they are actually describing.

**EDIT**: If you want to reason about the arguments explicitly, an algebraic analogy may help: We can regard each *pair* of arguments as describing a list as a "*difference*" between two lists, a **list difference**, also in analogy to *differential* Δ used in calculus.

For example, the "difference" between `[X,Y,Z|Rs]` and `Rs` is `[X,Y,Z]`. Hence, at least symbolically, we can write:

[image: List difference sample]

Let us denote with L, L<sub>0</sub>, L<sub>1</sub> and L<sub>2</sub> the lists that are described by such differences in the second clause:

[image: List differences]

Algebraically, we can think about L as the "*sum*" (concatenation) of the other lists:

[image: L is the sum]

For the other lists, we have:

[image: L0]

[image: L1]

[image: L2]

So, in total, we have:

[image: Total]

Note that no recursion is necessary to understand this. Instead, what matters is rather the *relation* between the arguments. Personally, I also find such a derivation less useful than the converse: I think it is much more important to notice this pattern when you write such code, because this means that you can *use DCG notation instead*, and significantly reduce the number of arguments that are passed around!

Comment: Great answer. Now if it only showed the steps as pictures with difference list. I don't expect that as I don't even take the time to do answers with difference list, but it would be nice.

Comment: Thank you very much! I gave it a try, please have a look. I used http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/prolog2017.pdf for orientation.

Answer (score 0):

```erlang
s(  A, A).               % s(0).
s(  A,       D) :-       % s(n):-
  l(A, B),               %   before,
     s(B, C),            %   s(n-1),
  r(      C, D).         %   after.

l(  [a | A], 
         A ).
r(  [b | B], 
         B ).
```

together define

```erlang
%% 1 
s(          [a , b | B1], B1):-
          l([a | A1],
                 A1 ),
              s( A1,      %s0%
                 A1 ),    %s0%
          r(    [b | B1],
                          B1 ).
```

and

```erlang
%% 2 
s(      [a , a , b , b | B2], B2):-
      l([a | A2],
             A2 ),
          l([a | A1],              %s1%
                 A1 ),             %s1%
              s( A1,      %s0%     %s1%
                 A1 ),    %s0%     %s1%
          r(    [b | B1],          %s1%
                     B1 ),         %s1%
      r(            [b | B2],
                              B2 ).
```

and

```erlang
%% 3 
s(  [a , a , a , b , b , b | B3], B3):-
  l([a | A3],
         A3 ),
      l([a | A2],                            %s2%
             A2 ),                           %s2%
          l([a | A1],              %s1%      %s2%
                 A1 ),             %s1%      %s2%
              s( A1,      %s0%     %s1%      %s2%
                 A1 ),    %s0%     %s1%      %s2%
          r(    [b | B1],          %s1%      %s2%
                     B1 ),         %s1%      %s2%
      r(            [b | B2],                %s2%
                         B2 ),               %s2%
  r(                    [b | B3],
                                  B3 ).
```

and so on and so forth.

Comment: I hate to say it, but that is the most confusing answer I think I have seen on SO. Sorry. If it wasn't for the fact that I understand the question, Prolog list and DCG I wouldn't even begin to understand that answer.

Comment: @GuyCoder thanks for the feedback, it's appreciated. Maybe I'll try adding some verbal explanations later... what's missing is a feedback by someone who unlike us do not understand the question or DCG, like the OP. :) it's their feedback that would really be valuable here. the problem with learning new things is that one can't unlearn them; so I imagine it's not confusing *to you*, you just think it'd be confusing to newbies (is that right?). I was hoping that the answer above would indeed provide visual cues and would thus be illuminating in some sense or other for such persons...

Comment: `it'd be confusing to newbies (is that right?)` Yes

Comment: The reason I recognize it and understand it is because I have used similar patterns in understanding Prolog. My current thought on why it looks hard to understand is that you are carrying state from line to line but not explaining what that the state is or how it is being modified. Also I find that the concept of a stack frame tends to help.